# How to extract daily views and subscribers gained with the help of YouTube API

Tags: api, view, youtube, analytics

I’m working on a project , where I have to retrieve channel data . That is views , likes , dislikes, subscribers gained  and Total subscribers between specific dates.
How can I extract with the help of YouTube analytics API. so that I can automate the process.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify the programming language you want to use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to see what you need to give so we can help, and update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.